# Complex non diagonizble orthogonal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exists a complex non diagonizable otrthogonal matrix?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you mean complex orthogonal matrices rather than unitary matrices. Then the answer is yes. See theorem 1.2.3 of Olga Ruff, [*The Jordan Canonical Forms of Complex Orthogonal and Skew-symmetric Matrices: Characterization and Examples*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.146.5519&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (Master Thesis). In particular, the minimum possible size of a nondiagonalisable complex orthogonal matrix is $3\times3$, and any nontrivial Jordan block of odd size for the eigenvalues $1$ or $-1$ is similar to a complex orthogonal matrix.